# How to change border colour in dropdown in fluent ui?

Tags: fluent-ui, fluentui-react

`<Dropdown/>` has styles props. which expects `IDropdownStyles`.But not able to change border outline colour. I tried this,

```
root: {

    width: 300, color: "red", backgroundColor: "red", borderColor: "red",
    borderTopColor: "red",
    outlineColor: "red",
    borderRightColor: "red",


  },
  dropdown: {
    width: 300, color: "red", backgroundColor: "red", borderColor: "blue",
    borderTopColor: "red"
    , outlineColor: "red",
    borderRightColor: "red",
  },
```

But the colour is not reflected. Is any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `title` property inside `styles`:

```js
<Dropdown
  ...
  styles={{
    title: {
      borderColor: 'red',
    }
  }}
/>
```

Codepen working [example](https://codepen.io/savkelita/pen/ExwqBqq?editors=0010).